# Iterate over Mongo results without running out of memory

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to find keywords in the name/description/tags, etc. of each document and remove them if they are found. I'm new to Mongo, so I'm following a similar script in the existing codebase. First, get the `MongoCursor` and only get the fields we'll be checking:

```
    /** @var MongoCursor $products */
    $products = $collection->find(
        ['type' => ['$in' => ['PHONES', 'TABLETS']], 'supplier.is_awful' => ['$exists' => true]],
        ['details.name' => true, 'details.description' => true]
    );
```

Then, iterate through each document, then check each of the properties for the values we're interested in:

```
/** @var \Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager $manager */
$manager = new Manager();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    // Find objectionable words in the content and remove these documents
    foreach (["suckysucky's", "deuce", "a z z"] as $word) {
        if (false !== strpos(mb_strtolower($product['details']['name']), $word)
          || false !== strpos(mb_strtolower($product['details']['description']), $word)) {
                $object = $manager->find(\App\Product::class, $product['_id']);
                $manager->remove($object);
        }
    }
}
// Persist to DB
$manager->flush();
```

The problem is that the database has hundreds of thousands of records, and it looks like iterating over the `MongoCursor`, the memory usage goes up and up until it runs out:

```
Now at (0) 20035632
Now at (100) 24446048
Now at (200) 32190312
Now at (300) 36098208
Now at (400) 42433656
Now at (500) 45204376
Now at (600) 50664808
Now at (700) 54916888
Now at (800) 59847312
Now at (900) 65145808
Now at (1000) 70764408
```

Is there a way for me to iterate over the `MongoCursor` without running out of memory (I've tried unsetting the various objects at different points, but no luck there)? Alternatively, is this a query that can be run directly in Mongo? I've looked at the docs, and I saw some hope in `$text`, but it looks like I need to have an index there (I don't), and there can only be one text index per collection.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am also seeing the same issue with my cursor taking up more and more memory without any obvious way to stop it.

Comment: @Boerema unfortunately, no. I simply increased PHP's memory_limit in the script. As far as I could tell (it's been a while and it's foggy), the leak is real

Answer (score 0):

You don't need fulltext index to find a substring: the right way is using a [regex](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongoregex.php) and then return only the "_id" value, something like:

```
$mongore = new MongoRegex("/suckysucky's|deuce|a z z/i")
$products = $collection->find(
    ['type' => ['$in' => ['PHONES', 'TABLETS']], 
     'supplier.is_awful' => ['$exists' => true],
     '$or': [['details.name' => $mongore],
             ['details.description' => $mongore]]]
    ['_id' => true]
);
```

I'm not sure about the exact PHP syntax, but the key is an inclusive $or filter with the same mongodb regex on the two fields.

Comment: ...of course you'll then loop results to remove all the _id from $manager collection; an optimization could be bulk remove by giving the whole list of $id (or at least a lot of them, the limit is the usual 16Gb of BSON) with an "$in" clause, so you could get rid of a lot of database roundtrip.